# Can you have more than one production database in Heroku?

Tags: postgresql, heroku

In Heroku, is it possible to have more than one "production" Postgres database?  In other words, let's say that (for whatever reason), I want to have both a "crane" instance and a "kappa" instance.  It sure seems like Heroku would be happy to let me give them the money :) but, it doesn't want to seem to let me do this.  Am I missing something?  Is it the new dashboard/UI that's not letting me?  Do I have to create a separate app for the new db?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to provision multiple production databases, however they are then differentiated by the COLOR in their config name. In order to add two you would:

```
heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:crane
heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:kappa
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Actually, I couldn't use your answer (although I definitely believe that it works).  The problem is that while I maintain the site, and have the "owner" credentials, I have myself set up as a collaborator and login with the CLI though a separate account.  Therefore, I usually just use the UI when doing Addons.  The new UI/dashboard will not allow me to do it.  But, after reverting to the old UI, it worked fine.